# In Web2py, orderby on integer field treated as a string

Tags: web2py

I have a query :-

```
result = db(db.tag_count.user_id == user_id).select(db.tag_count.name, db.tag_count.count, orderby=~ db.tag_count.count, limitby=(0, 10))
```

Where the table is defined as

```
db.define_table('tag_count',
                Field('name'),
                Field('user_id', db.auth_user),
                Field('count', 'integer'),
                format='%(title)s')
```

The aim of the query is to return the top 10 rows containing the highest integer value of tag_count.

In fact it returns the highest string value of tag_count for example 21 , 2, 12, 2 i.e 2>12 . I would expected 21, 12, 2, 1

I am using web2py 2.3.2 and sqlite as the database.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you originally define the `count` field as a string field (i.e., `Field('count')`), and then later switch to integer? If so, you may need to fix the table in SQLite. See [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Fixing-broken-migrations) for more details.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for the pointer. In the end I dropped the original table, created a new one and populated it with sample data. Same problem. So it would seem not to be the case. I am wondering if there is some interaction between SQLite's type system and web2py, but this seems so fundamental I can't believe I'm the only one coming up against it - suggesting something stupid that I have done.

Comment: As Massimo [pointed out](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/Hl_Qi4jDKTg/RyBl9jpnQ-kJ) on the mailing list, it is not a general problem with SQLite and web2py, so must be something with your setup/code. In addition to dropping the table in SQLite, try doing a `fake_migrate` on the table or deleting the table's associated *.table file from the application's /databases folder before re-creating the table.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I'll have a further play

Comment: Right, on further inspection, recreating the table /did/ fix the ordering (think my brain started ordering alphabetically as well....) - so it's clear that this is as a result of starting out with an unspecified type - it defaulting to string and then failing, meaning that I changed to integer, committed and forgot about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of people like me in the future. With thanks to Anthony's comment above.

The original table did not define the field to be an integer and defaulted to string. I realised that I needed an integer and updated the field. SQlite is not able to migrate the type and so it remained a string.

Solution is to export table, recreate table with integer and ensure that reinsertion type is an integer.

See [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Fixing-broken-migrations) for more details